# log4j2 JDBC manager cannot connect to the database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, log4j2

I'm trying to configure log4j v2 with mysql, but it returns this error:

```
2014-08-01 15:35:24,819 ERROR Unable to write to database [jdbcManager{ description=databaseAppender, bufferSize=0, connectionSource=factory{ public static java.sql.Connection it.prisma.presentationlayer.webui.ConnectionFactory.getDatabaseConnection() }, tableName=logs, columns=[ { name=message, layout=%message, literal=null, timestamp=false } ] }] for appender [databaseAppender]. org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Cannot write logging event or flush buffer; JDBC manager cannot connect to the database.

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to obtain connection from factory method.

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://10.41.1.68:3306/test
```

My configuration is similar to [doc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#JDBCAppender), with the only difference of this:

```
new PoolableConnectionFactory(connectionFactory, pool, null, "SELECT 1", false, false, Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);
```

I think that my tomcat7 is well configured because I can log with log4j v1.

Comment: Is your MySql JDBC driver available on the classpath?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok the solution is:

1- create a Connection Factory class

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource;
import org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool;


public class ConnectionFactory {

    private static interface Singleton {
        final ConnectionFactory INSTANCE = new ConnectionFactory();
    }

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    private ConnectionFactory() {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("user", "root");
        properties.setProperty("password", "root");

        GenericObjectPool<PoolableConnection> pool = new GenericObjectPool<PoolableConnection>();
        DriverManagerConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(
                "jdbc:mysql://example.org:3306/exampleDb", properties
        );
        new PoolableConnectionFactory(connectionFactory, pool, null, "SELECT 1", 3, false, false, Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);
        this.dataSource = new PoolingDataSource(pool);
    }

    public static Connection getDatabaseConnection() throws SQLException {
        return Singleton.INSTANCE.dataSource.getConnection();
    }
}
```

2- create a configuration file into src/main/resources called log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="TRACE" monitorInterval="30">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <JDBC name="databaseAppender" tableName="logs">
            <ConnectionFactory class="my.pack.ConnectionFactory"
                method="getDatabaseConnection" />
            <!-- <Column name="id" literal="LOGGING.APPLICATION_LOG_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL" /> -->
            <Column name="date" isEventTimestamp="true" />
            <Column name="level" pattern="%level" />
            <Column name="message" pattern="%message" />
            <Column name="class" pattern="%class" /> 
        </JDBC>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="databaseAppender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

3- create a table like this:
[image]

4- add mysql connector to {tomcat}/bin

Maven hints:

```
    <commons-dbcp.version>1.4</commons-dbcp.version>

    <commons-pool.version>1.6</commons-pool.version>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-dbcp.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-pool.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: GenericObjectPool doesn't take any paramters??? why doesn't it work in my project?

Comment: Now it does it seems, I could not get this one to work either. Found this one from your other question which helped to solve the problem. <https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=commons-dbcp.git;a=blob_plain;f=doc/PoolingDataSourceExample.java;hb=HEAD>

Comment: @Kjenos  You have to add a dependency to get that functionality.  See the "Maven hints" now in the answer.

Comment: Works very well. The only outstanding issue, is how to generate the NEXTVAL for the primary key of the logging table. This is not clear. I am using an Oracle database. Thank you VERY much for the answer, it was extremely helpful :=)

Comment: I'm getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.com.prodist.database.ConnectionFactory cannot be found by org.apache.logging.log4j.api_2.11.0 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.com.prodist.database.ConnectionFactory cannot be found by org.apache.logging.log4j.api_2.11.0 when I try to apply those configurations in my OSGi application, any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

For future readers.  I got this error when I was using hikari.
My code (that is BAD and does not work)....is below.

So I changed to Mateo's answer (here at this question, the answer he posted), and I've back in business.

I'm leaving this answer, in case someone else hits the issue.

PS  My logging dependencies were "clean".   see https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/log4j2.html

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
```

..

```
    <HikariCP.version>3.1.0</HikariCP.version>
```

..

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;

public class LogDataSource {

    private static LogDataSource logDataSource = new LogDataSource();

    public static final String ENVIRONMENT = "environment";
    private Properties prop;
    public String environment;
    private HikariDataSource hikariDataSource;

    private LogDataSource() {
        try {
            environment = System.getProperty(ENVIRONMENT);
            String url = getProperty("LogDatabaseConnectionString");
            HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
            hikariConfig.setPoolName("eisltier2LogPool");
            hikariConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
            hikariConfig.setDataSourceClassName(getProperty("dataSourceClassName"));

            String dsClassName = hikariConfig.getDataSourceClassName();
            try {
                Class.forName(dsClassName);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new NullPointerException(String.format("DataSourceClassName did not load. (DataSourceClassName='%s')", dsClassName));
            }

            hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(Integer.valueOf(getProperty("hikari.maximumPoolSize")));
            hikariConfig.setIdleTimeout(Integer.valueOf(getProperty("hikari.idleTimeout")));
            Properties dsProperties = new Properties();
            dsProperties.put("url", url);
            hikariConfig.setDataSourceProperties(dsProperties);
            HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
            this.hikariDataSource = hikariDataSource;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static DataSource getConnection() {
        DataSource returnItem = logDataSource.hikariDataSource;
        return returnItem;
    }

    public String getProperty(String key) throws IOException {

        if (prop == null) {
            prop = new Properties();
            try(InputStream inputConnectionStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("connection.properties");){
            prop.load(inputConnectionStream);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IOException(e);
            }
        }
        String value = ((environment == null || environment == "") ? prop.getProperty(key)
                : prop.getProperty(environment + "." + key));
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your getConnection() method is wrong, it should return a Connection from the logDataSource.hikariDataSource.getConnection()