# GenericObjectPool<PoolableConnection>

Tags: mysql, jdbc, log4j2

i think i found a pretty good answer for my question here:
[log4j2-jdbc-manager-cannot-connect-to-the-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081829/log4j2-jdbc-manager-cannot-connect-to-the-database)

I tried to implement the code in my project and everything worked fine beside of this little error:

```
GenericObjectPool<PoolableConnection>
```

> Type GenericObjectPool does not take parameters.

I don't know how I can do a workaround, or what as to be changed.

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=commons-dbcp.git;a=blob_plain;f=doc/PoolingDataSourceExample.java;hb=HEAD

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Then in your code add:

```
import org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.